# "Undefined index" when quoting array key

Tags: php, forms

I have a form in `index.php`

```
<?php 
  echo '<form action="update_act.php" method="POST">';
  echo '<input type="submit" name="'.$row['act_name'].'" value="edit">
  echo </form>
?>
```

Here $row['act_name'] is a value fetched from database.

My update_act.php file is

```
<?php
   echo "Old Activity Name : ".$_POST['$row[\'act_name\']'];
?>
```

But I am getting an error `Undefined index: $row['act_name'] in C:\wamp\www\ps\activity\update_act.php`.

I want to have different names for different `submits` but I am not able to get its value in another page. Is there any way for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PHP only substitutes variables  enclosed in double quotes `"`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) . What you want is:

```
echo "Old Activity Name : ". $_POST[$row['act_name']]
```

---

But your whole form does not make any sense. The output you get would be:

```
Old Activity Name : edit
```

because this is the value of the submit button.

**Can you please clarify your question, what do you want to achieve?** Here are some thoughts from my side:

Maybe what you want is more like:

```
<form action="update_act.php" method="POST">;
    <input type="hidden" name="act_name" value="<?php echo $row[act_name] ?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="edit">
</form>

// ---- other file ---

<?php
   echo "Old Activity Name : ".$_POST['act_name'];
?>
```

---

Why do you want *to have different names for different submits* ?
**Do you want to differentiate between different actions?** If so, it is easier you the buttons have the same name and you check against their values, e.g.:

```
<form action="update_act.php" method="POST">;
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="edit">
</form>

<form action="update_act.php" method="POST">;
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="delete">
</form>
```

and then

```
<?php 
if($_POST['submit'] == 'edit') {

}
else if ($_POST['submit'] == 'delete') {

}
```

Comment: I am still getting an error.Here i want to do actually is the data fetched from table $row['act_name'] has to be updated in other page update_act.php and while displaying the old value it gives an error in the update_act.php.

Comment: @Satish: What is the error and how is the value updated? You have no form field that takes a new value.

Answer (score 3):

I don't exactly know, what you're trying to do, but if the value of variable $row['act_name'] is same in both of the cases (form page and update script), then you can access to that this way:

```
echo "Old Activity Name : ".$_POST[$row['act_name']];
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `$_POST[$row['act_name']]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
   echo "Old Activity Name : ".$_POST['$row[\'act_name\']'];
```

should be

```
   echo "Old Activity Name : ".$_POST["$row[act_name]"];
```

or

```
   echo "Old Activity Name : ".$_POST[$row[act_name]];
```